# visual studio stops and restarts if I run cordova application

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, hybrid-mobile-app, visual-studio-cordova

I am using CLI tool to build cordova app on windows phone (Universal).
It was working fine until I install the apache cordova tools for visual studio 2015.
Now when I click on any button on the home page app will crash and VS2015 will be restarted. I have uninstall the Cordova tool but the issue still persists.
But i am able to run the application on SIM/Device after the crash.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you try using HoctkeyApp to get the crash log. You can refer to the documentation [here](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/add-analytics/).

Comment: Sure, I can give a try.

Comment: Hi, I found a root cause for the above issue. Visual Studio stops and restarts if i add jquery.mobile.1.4.5.min.js into my project. Yet to figure out the solution for this issue.

@ Elvis, Hockey App supports only native windows phone Apps and Cordova Windows 8 apps but not windows phone 8.1 built from cordova.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a root cause for the above issue. Visual Studio stops and restarts if i add jquery.mobile.1.4.5.min.js into my project. Yet to figure out the solution for this issue.
But I got to know the work around for it. just use the library jquery.mobile.1.4.0.min.js